# How to make a plot in R grouping by the column value

Tags: r, plot

I have a table containing three columns: two types of time (planned time vs really spent time) and a number marking a month (but for each month there is a ton of entries). It looks like that

```
month planned spent
1        40     30
1        20     20
2        10      NA
```

etc.

I'm interesting in the percent of spent regarding the planned (and to check if there is a correlation between the quantity of planned time and the percent of spent time). Of course I can count it for each month using:

```
100*sum(final$spent[final$month == 1], na.rm = T)/sum(final$planned[final$month == 1])
```

Now I want to build a plot. Planned time is one axis, percent is another one, while the month would be specified with a colour.

I'm trying to do it in lattice with

```
with(final, xyplot(sum(planned) ~ 100*sum(spent, na.rm = T)/sum(planned), group=month))
```

but I get only one point on my plot.

I need advice as to how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: this is not a reproducible example (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And you also have some typos in your script (e.e Month vs month)

Comment: What is `final$fact`?

Comment: @TejaK , sorry, I edited the post. Now I hope everything is clear

Answer (score 1):

Hadley Wickham has created several R packages that are very handy for doing this sort of thing. I like plyr for the data summarizing you're talking about and ggplot2 for plotting. Here's how I'd do that with your data.

```
 final <- data.frame(month = c(1, 1, 2),
               planned = c(40, 20, 10),
               spent = c(30, 20, NA))

 library(plyr)
 summary <- ddply(final, "month", function (x) c(
  sumplanned = sum(x$planned, na.rm = T),
  sumspent = sum(x$spent, na.rm = T),
  percent = sum(x$spent, na.rm = T)/sum(x$planned, na.rm = T)
))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(summary, aes(x = sumplanned, y = percent, color = as.factor(month))) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: thank you so much!

But I need actually one more thing: how to give different colours to my 12 points (according to the month they reflect)?

Comment: Edited my answer for that. Just add the "color = month" as noted above. There are lots of resources online for how to use ggplot2.